# Html-css - Меняется стиль блока после добавления div

Tags: html, css

Почему после добавление divа, стиль второго блока становится таким же как и стиль первого?

http://jsfiddle.net/rJKn5/3/

HTML

```
<div id="inside">
    <a href="#"></a>
    <a href="#"></a>
   <!-- <div></div> -->
</div>
```

CSS

```
#inside {
    overflow:hidden;
    outline:1px solid black;
    width: 443px;
    margin: 10px auto;
}
#inside a {
    display: block;
    background: #0000FF;
    float: left;
    width: 140px;
    height: 52px;
}
#inside a:last-child {
    background: #FF0000;
    margin-left: 79px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что последняя <a> перестает попадать под селектор a:last-child

Попробуйте обернуть ссыллки в блок, например [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/rJKn5/4/)